# Change date time format from YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to YYYY.MM.DD HH:MM:SS in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, date

I have a table with a column `RequestDate` with following format `2019-12-01 00:00:00:000`. I want to see results like this: `2019.12.01 00:00:00:000`.

I used this command

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), RequestDate, 104) AS finaldate
```

From the above query I am seeing results as 2019.12.01, but I am missing time (00:00:00:000) - how can I keep along with time. I want final results like `2019.12.01 00:00:00:000`

Comment: I firmly believe that all formatting should be done in the presentation layer, and not in SQL, you should keep dates as dates until the last possible moment, so that if any processes between SQL and the client wants to do any further manipulation, or sorting, or deal with time zones they can, without having to convert back to a date (which can be risky in itself, 2019.12.01 could be 1st December or 12th January depending on regional settings)

Comment: If you must convert your date to a different format that isn't specified as a style for `CONVERT`, then you can always use [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but beware it [doesn't scale very well](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a built-in format specifier for this. But you could do:

```
replace(convert(varchar, requestDate, 121), '-', '.')
```

`121` gives you format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`. You can then replace each occurence of `'-'` with `':'`.

Note that this assumes that you have a `datetime` datatype to start with. If you have a string, then no need to `convert()`, you can just `replace()`.

Comment: thank you so much ...it will helped me now I'm seeing expected format....have a pleasant day sir . thank you so much

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) *(I know in this case there is no real downside to it, but others that see this post may not know the internal rules of how SQL Sever deals with varchar with no length)*